# Campos dinámicos en Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

Tengo un problema con un informe el cual el título de una tarea le hemos dejado crecer para que puedan salir el texto al completo y no se corte, el problema viene que cuando el titulo tiene una segunda línea se monta con la de la descripción. No nos vale bajar el campo de la descripción, que cuando el título tiene solo una línea deja una separación grande.

Existe algún código dentro de crystal report (no lo desarrollamos desde visual studio, si no desde la propia aplicación de crystal) para solucionar este tipo de problema, por ahora no he encontrado nada similar en la web.

Un saludo

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.